# Highlight and Hide DIV onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, jquery-animate

How to **Animate/Highlight** the Div **before** hide, when click on **desired** Div?

```
Here is my JS DEMO:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7tK3/17/

I want to animate or highlight the **Clicked or Selected** Div first and then its should hide.

**Here is the HTML :**

```
<div id="response_1" class="container">
    <span id="1" class="hide_content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Here To Hide First Div</a>
    </span>  
</div>

<br>

<div id="response_2" class="container">
    <span id="2" class="hide_content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Here To Hide Second Div</a>
    </span>  
</div>

<br>

<div id="response_3" class="container">
    <span id="3" class="hide_content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Here To Hide Third Div</a>
    </span>  
</div>
```

**Here is CSS:**

```
.container{
    border:#666666 solid 1px;  
    padding:4px;
}
```

**Here is JS:**

```
$('.hide_content').click(function ()
                         {
                           var current_number = $(this).attr("id");  
                           $('#response_'+current_number).hide();
                         });
```

Comment: OK done. Now please remove the down rating from my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/L7tK3/22/)

```
$('.hide_content').click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".container").animate({ "background-color": "yellow" }, 500, "linear").
            delay().fadeOut(500)
});
```

Animating the background color requires the jQuery.Color plugin (or jQuery UI).

Comment: Well i want to highlight the DIV not the text

Comment: And how about if we change border color only ?

Comment: @Necromancer with `animate` you can change (almost) any CSS setting that you want.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search instantly led me here:
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
.hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Come on.